# Use @types for Typescript npm library without requiring that upstream projects install that dependency

Tags: typescript, npm, systemjs

We have an npm library package written in TypeScript that contains various utilities for other projects to use.  We'll just call this library `lib-utils`.

One of the libraries used by `lib-utils` is `d3`.  `lib-utils` has both a peerDependency and a devDependency on `d3` as well as a devDependency on `@types/d3`.

Not all projects that make use of the `lib-utils` package will make use of the `d3` code in `lib-utils`, so I don't want those projects to be forced to supply it.

However, in order to use `d3` internally, several of `lib-util`'s source files are importing `d3` using `import * as d3 from "d3"` in order to get compile-time checks.  That seems to place a runtime requirement on `d3` for any upstream library that uses `lib-utils` even if they don't use the `d3` parts of it.  When the upstream project loads in the browser I get 404 errors as `lib-utils` loads and tries to load `d3`.

I've tried using each of the following:

1. `/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/d3/index.d.ts" />`
2. `/// <reference type="d3">`

inside `lib-utils` where d3 is needed, but I can't get past the compilation issues until I use the regular module import, and that seems to be the source of my problem.

How can I get TypeScript type checking in `lib-utils` without requiring that consumers of the `lib-utils` package also supply d3 even if they're not using it?

I'm using systemjs for packaging.  A solution that simply instructs systemjs to ignore d3 might work, but I'd prefer to solve this in `lib-utils` and not in every consumer.

Comment: I have found a solution that sits on the systemjs side involving adding a map under the `lib-utils` package entry that points `d3` to the `@empty` package.  Looks like this:

`packages: {
  "lib-utils": { ... map: {"d3": "@empty"} ... }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `systemjs` config as in your comment, you can import only the types you need in your import syntax.

The problem is when you say `import * as d3 from 'd3'`, the compiler assume you need the whole `d3` library, including the code portion.

You should do:

```
import { SomeType, SomeOtherType } from 'd3'

// code away
```

When importing only types, the compiler will remove that import from your JS.